# Notification system in symfony 3.1

Tags: php, symfony-3.1

I use symfony 3.1. I want to create a notification system in my application in symfony. I have created an entity named **notification** to save notifications. So when a user creates, edits or removes a record in the database, I want to save this action in a **notification table**. I used HasLifecycleCallbacks() annotation method and it forced me to create a controller object in my entity but nothing has worked. How can i do it? Is there another solution?

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CM\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */

 class User extends BaseUser {
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", unique=true, length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $nom;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="integer", unique=true, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $numero;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set numero
 *
 * @param integer $numero
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setNumero($numero)
{
    $this->numero = $numero;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get numero
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getNumero()
{
    return $this->numero;
}

/**
* @ORM\PreRemove
*/
public function notify(){
  $controlleur = new RemoveController();
  $em = $controlleur->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $notif = new Notification();
  $notif->setOperation('recording');
  $notif->setUser('William');
  $em->persist($notif);
  $em->flush();   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved my problem. I had not read very well the documentation. And then i did some more research. So here is a solution that works for me in symfony 3.1.
I used dependency injection. I have injected ManagerRegistry to have the entity manager service and TokenStorage for tokenStorage service to know the current user connected.
I have created a folder name **NotificationDB**. And then i have also created a class name **NotificationDB.php** which here is the code. For this example, i suppose that i have a form to register a **foo** entity.

```
namespace CM\GestionBundle\NotificationBD;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage; 
use \CM\GestionBundle\Entity\Notification;    

class NotificationBD {  

private $managerRegistry;

/**
 * @var TokenStorage
 */
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
public function notifyEvent(){
    $entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    $notif = new Notification();
    $notif->setDateNotif(new \Datetime());
    $notif->setUser($user);
    $notif->setActionNotif('recording');
    $notif->setObjetNotif('foo');
    $entityManager->persist($notifEdition);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
}
```

In **CM\GestionBundle\Resources\config**, i have configure as service in **services.yml** file which here is the content :

```
    CM_gestion.notification:
        class: CM\GestionBundle\NotificationBD\NotificationBD
        arguments: ['@doctrine', '@security.token_storage']
```

And then i have created a listener for which will call this service. For this example, i will create a **foo entity listener** which will listen register event and use the service to persist the **notification** entity. Here is my **foo listener**.

```
namespace CM\GestionBundle\DoctrineListener;
use CM\GestionBundle\NotificationBD\NotificationBD;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use \CM\GestionBundle\Entity\Foo;

class FooListener {

/**
* @var NotificationBD
*/
private $notificationBD;

public function __construct(NotificationBD $notificationBD) {
    $this->notificationBD = $notificationBD;
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $args->getObject();

    if (!$entity instanceof Foo) {
        return;
    }
    $this->notificationBD->notifyEvent();
}
}
```

In **CM\GestionBundle\Resources\config**
The last thing to do is to add this listener in **services.yml** file. Here is the content

```
CM_gestion.doctrine_listener.foo:
    class:  CM\GestionBundle\DoctrineListener\FooListener
    arguments:
        - "@CM_gestion.notification"
    tags:
        - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist}
```

That all. this solution work for me in symfony 3.1. This problem can be marked as resolved. Thank